# VBA Parse Nested JSON

Tags: json, vba, excel

VBA Noob here. Please excuse any gaps in terminology etc.

I am trying to parse a JSON file into a spreadsheet using VBA-JSON v2.2.3 (c) Tim Hall - https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON.

The JSON file looks like this:

```
{
  "site": "{5BEC7C29-FF95-4ECC-9314-064B52618EEE}",
  "from": "2017-01-16",
  "to": "2017-01-22",
  "timeSheet": [
    {
      "date": "2017-01-16",
      "person": "{E2A5FDE1-33F8-43CA-A01D-5DD4A3A5E23A}",
      "personName": "James Smith",
      "company": "{B03CF7B3-0BE9-44B4-8E55-47782FDD87C0}",
      "companyName": "Acme Company Ltd",
      "minutes": "510",
      "activities": [
        {
          "name": "Training",
          "code": "TR",
          "minutes": "240"
        },
        {
          "name": "Administration",
          "code": "AD",
          "minutes": "150"
        },
        {
          "name": "Payroll",
          "code": "PR",
          "minutes": "60"
        },
        {
          "name": "Meal break",
          "code": "",
          "minutes": "60"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

There may be any number of 'timeSheet' records, as well as any number of 'Activities' within each timeSheet including zero.

I want a row in the spreadsheet for each activity, with the name and other data outputted next to that days activities. Essentially showing a log of all the activities done, for how long and by who. To complicate issues, I still need the name etc outputting even if no activities are recorded. I will then fill with 'unallocated time' or something similar.

Below is as far as I have got (abridged), with an updated count of the activities occurring every loop. This feels a little hacky and doesn't give me what I am looking for, often adding additional rows and sometimes missing activities entirely.

```
i = 2
j = 1
activCount = CStr(JSON("timeSheet")(1)("activities").Count)

If activCount = 0 Then activCount = 1

    ws.Cells(i, 1) = JSON("site")
    ws.Cells(i, 2) = JSON("from")
    ws.Cells(i, 3) = JSON("to")


For Each item In JSON("timeSheet")
    For j = 1 To activCount
        On Error Resume Next
        ws.Cells(i, 4) = item("date")
        ws.Cells(i, 5) = item("personName")
        ws.Cells(i, 6) = item("companyName")
        ws.Cells(i, 7) = item("minutes")
        ws.Cells(i, 9) = item("activities")(j)("name")
        ws.Cells(i, 10) = item("activities")(j)("code")
        ws.Cells(i, 11) = item("activities")(j)("minutes")

        activCount = CStr(JSON("timeSheet")(i)("activities").Count)
        If activCount = 0 Then activCount = 1
        i = i + 1

    Next
Next
```

Can someone help? I have run out of ideas and have been working it for some time! Thank you. :)

Comment: Welcome to [so]!  ...I'm sorry but if you're a self-declared VBA Noob, this ancient, half-working `VBA-JSON` module is pretty much the worst place to begin.  Believe me, I've wasted a lot of time on it.

Comment: If the JSON file is that small, you should be able to parse it without issue using text functions (mainly `InStr` and `Mid`, or else `RegEx`).  There's a lot of examples around.  Sadly, JSON and VBA don't get along too well.

Comment: You can loop using `For Each act in item("activities")`

Comment: @ashleedawg - I've never had an issue with that module: care to share some specifics around why you recommend against it?

Comment: @Tim - I've never *not* had an issue.  It could be partially related to the fact that the JSON sources I've needed to work with are *extremely* large, also in the real world, files aren't always gonna be 100% perfect structure, but these kinds of things shouldn't be such a problem with data coming from well-known sources such as Google or NAVCAN.  (Equally frustrating for me are Office's supposed built-in JSON / XML tools, which work great - except for when they don't.)  I up building my own JSON import utility, which even built half-cocked, still does it's job better than the others.

Comment: ...that being said, it's only *my opinion*, and I'm interested to see what it takes for you or anyone to get the OP up and running.  Should be easy on such a simple file. (Or could've been full automated already by using good ol' text functions.)  What about Office's "built-in functionality"?  Have you had any luck with that?   Surely that should be the preferable option over a 3rd party "hack".  (Nothing against Tim Hall; he's brilliant and made it further than Microsoft did.)

Comment: @ashleedawg - thanks for the response.  No, not the same person.  I don't think it's fair though to expect a library to correctly parse malformed JSON (just as you wouldn't expect that from an XML parser: it's not the parser's job to fix broken syntax).  My experience with VBA-JSON has mostly been with small to medium-sized JSON responses (pretty much all from my own endpoints), so I've not worked with very large datasets.  I've not used any of the "built-in" JSON import functionality in Excel: I never had much luck with the XML-mapping stuff so I'm a bit put off by that...

Comment: I don't know about "unfairness"; it's my opinion -- and one I would *love* to be proven wrong on.  Perhaps the fact that you control the source data helps, because it's much easier to account for a single unusual set of brackets or unexpected tag in datasets used worldwide (for example, Google 's Location History data).  It's also not fair to discount Microsoft's XML functionality based on another tool (plus I was hoping you'd have a magic answer on getting that working to.)  How about Excel 2016's XML functions, `WEBSERVICE` and `FILTERXML`?  I never see anyone discussing/recommending those.

Comment: @ashleedawg - I didn't mean to assign any opinions you might not have - perhaps I misunderstood you there. I have used Microsoft's XML tech/libraries quite a bit (and never had much of a problem with how they operate), just never used the "consumer" interface in Excel: on a brief look it gets too tricky too quickly when dealing with any depth of nested data. As for Excel 2016: the folks I work with are still on Excel 2013, so no WEBSERVICE for me yet (hence my current use of VBA-JSON & co.)

Comment: Currently the dataset I am dealing with is relatively small. 100 staff over 20 sites completing an average of 3 different activities per day. But I would like a solution that is sustainable as the company grows. In terms of the parser, I haven't had any real issues - my issues seem to mainly be about accessing and outputting the information in the resulting object/dictionary. Probably quite trivial stuff for those with a decent foundation in coding! :)

Comment: I'm encouraged to see this sparking some discussion. I have already had so much help from this community by searching existing questions, so it's awesome to see everyone so willing to give a leg up to a new user. I'll look to pay it forward as I improve. Thanks everyone. :)

Comment: @ashleedawg you wrote that you have built your own JSON import utility, could you please share your solution, or even post an answer implementing it, just as an example?

Comment: @omegastripes - oh it ain't pretty - No fancy coding or remarkable execution speeds, and very specific to my purposes - but it is forgiving of minor json syntax mistakes when encountered (as opposed to returning "nothing") and of course I can tweak it when necessary.  It was mishmashed together with good ol' looped text functions and bits & pieces of RegEx.  If I could better wrap my head around RegEx, I feel like it has everything a JSON parser would need. Might take multiple passes of the complete file, but seems to me that every bit of data would be more extracted than existing "solutions".

Comment: ...my point wasn't that I have a magic answer, rather that I was forced to start from scratch because I haven't been able to find anything else to work reliably with "any" json (regardless of size or minor flaws). There is an MS Access "JSON Transform" utility of which I created the prototype (based off VBA-JSON) before it was taken over by an acquaintance since it, once again, was/is simply unable too handle my needs. He's got his newest version for sale & a previous version as a trial [here](http://www.mendipdatasystems.co.uk/jatfa-older-versions/4594110256). Maybe it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me:

```
Sub TestJson2()

    Dim ts, act
    Dim Json As Object, c As Range

    'reading json from a worksheet cell...
    Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(Range("A3").Value)

    Set c = ActiveSheet.Range("C5")

    'loop over timesheets
    For Each ts In Json("timeSheet")
        'loop over timesheet activities
        For Each act In ts("activities")

            c.Resize(1, 11).Value = Array(Json("site"), Json("from"), Json("to"), _
                                       ts("date"), ts("personName"), ts("companyName"), _
                                       ts("minutes"), act("name"), act("code"), _
                                       act("minutes"))
            Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
        Next act
    Next ts

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! I will have a look at implementing this later today and feedback how it goes.

Comment: Finally had a chance to get back to this project. Unfortunately the above solution doesn't work as it only outputs records with an activity attached. This isn't always the case.