# how to pull elements from a list in vba

Tags: vba

I have extract something like this from a database:

[{"identifier":{"strategyType":"element1"},"elnSchedules":[{"paymentDate":["element2","element2"]},{"paymentDate":["element2","element2"]}],"composition":{"components":[{"instrument":{"exerciseType":["element3","element3"]}},{"instrument":{"exerciseType":["element3","element3"]}}]},"links":[]}]

I want to build a vba and create a table in excel that has header: strategyType, paymentDate, exerciseType

and elements: element1, element2, element3 under the corresponding header(while each element can only appear once).

so far I have:
 For i = 1 To jsonO.Count
            'set headings
            If i = 1 Then
                j = 1
                For Each StrKey In jsonO(i).Keys()
                    activeWS.Cells(i + offset, j) = StrKey
                    j = j + 1
                Next
            End If

```
        j = 1
        For Each StrKey In jsonO(i).Keys()
            If (StrKey <> "links") Then
                activeWS.Cells(i + offset + 1, j) = jsonO(i)(StrKey)
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next
```

But this only extracts identifier, eLnschedules, and composition and not able to get into specific element.

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks.

-------------------NEW QUESTION----------------------

I used what's posted on the answer and was trying to build a new function under the function posted in the answer(while both of them are called by the main function):

Public Sub GetEndDate()

```
Dim activeWS As Worksheet
Set activeWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
Dim jsonStr As String, Json As Object, headers()
'headers = Array("strategyType", "paymentDate", "exerciseType")
jsonStr = [{"optionFeatures":{"Strike Setting":[{"endDate":["2018-10-16"]}]},"links":[]}] '<== read from cell
Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonStr)(1)
activeWS.Cells(1, 13) = Json("optionFeatures")("Strike Setting")("endDate")
```

End Sub

However it was not able to read from the string, or do I need to reset the lib again?

Thanks.

Comment: code = [{"identifier":{"strategyType":"element1"},"elnSchedules":[{"paymentDate":["element2","element2"]},{"paymentDate":["element2","element2"]}],"composition":{"components":[{"instrument":{"exerciseType":["element3","element3"]}},{"instrument":{"exerciseType":["element3","element3"]}}]},"links":[]}]

Comment: what do you mean by each element can only appear once? Does that appear you only want the first if it appears twice?

Comment: A list is not a VBA data type. Is this a string? Of course you can write a VBA program which will take such strings and use them to populate a table, although any such program will involve nontrivial parsing. What issued have you encountered in your attempts to write such a program? Please show some relevant code.

Comment: yep (as you can see there are several element2, while I only want the first one as they are all the same

Comment: This is a JSON string  but I think OP needs to examine the structure and clarify what they want from it.

Comment: yep it is a string, i just don't know how to grab those element from the string

Comment: elnSchedules, for example, is a collection with 2 items which are identical dictionaries containing a collection called instrument which repeats element 3 4 times. 2 in each collection.

Comment: you would use a JSON parser like JSONConverter.bas or Split function as you only want first occurences by the sounds of it.

Comment: This question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6627652/4996248

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [JSONConverter.bas](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) to parse the JSON string read in from a cell as shown below. This assumes you only want one instance of each value.

Note:

After adding in JSONConverter.bas you need to go VBE > Tools > References > Add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

Your JSON structure is as follows:

[image]

`[]` indicates a collection, items accessed by index starting from 1. `{}` indicates a dictionary with items accessed by key.

I traverse the tree using the appropriate syntax to retrieve the first occurrence of each element.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfoFromSheet()
    Dim jsonStr As String, Json As Object, headers()
    headers = Array("strategyType", "paymentDate", "exerciseType")
    jsonStr = [A1] '<== read from cell
    Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonStr)(1)

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1) = Json("identifier")("strategyType")
        .Cells(2, 2) = Json("elnSchedules")(1)("paymentDate")(1)
        .Cells(2, 3) = Json("composition")("components")(1)("instrument")("exerciseType")(1)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.? I tried to run it but it shows JsonConverter not defined. Thanks.

Comment: Did you download the .bas and add it to your project?

Comment: The converter works now, thanks. But what if some of the elements are missing/empty? As the code would not skip any empty elements...

Comment: You asked how to drill down. I am showing you how to think about it. Otherwise, you would need to loop testing with TypeName whether you are dealing with Dictionary or Collection.

Comment: Are some of the elements empty? See my answer here for looping https://stackoverflow.com/a/49011943/6241235