# VBA: Nested JSON Object Structure for UK Bank Holidays - Run Time Errors 13, 438 and 449

Tags: json, vba, object, ms-access, nested

I'm looking to import all England and Wales Bank Holidays from https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json and add them to a pre-created MS Access recordset (called "TestTable") using the MS Access VBA module. The code below opens and converts the json to a string, and then parses it using the JsonConverter.

This is where I seem to have hit a wall - I can't seem to get the right combo of Dictionaries and Collections to tell the VBA module the structure of the json file (I have no problem with creating a record in Access). After parsing the json, I'm getting one of two errors, most likely because what I think is supposed to be a dictionary (with {} brackets) and what I think is supposed to be a collection (with [] brackets) give me errors.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ImportBH()

    Dim Parsed As Dictionary
    Dim rsT As DAO.Recordset
    Dim jsonStr As String
    Dim dictionaryKey, var1 As Variant
    Dim initialCollection As Collection
    Set rsT = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TestTable")
    Dim httpobject As Object
    Set httpobject = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    httpobject.Open "GET", "https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json", False
    httpobject.Send
    jsonStr = httpobject.responsetext
    Set Parsed = ParseJson(jsonStr) 'parse json data
```

If I now use the line:

```
For Each dictionaryKey In Parsed("england-and-wales")
```

Then at the end of the "item" function in JsonConverter, I get a Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method.

On the other hand, if I use the line:

```
For Each dictionaryKey In Parsed.Keys
```

Then it works (using the "Keys" function in JsonConverter), and when I hover over "Parsed.Keys", it gives me "england-and-wales". However, at the first line of the following code, I get a Run-time error 13: Type mismatch.

```
        Set initialCollection = dictionaryKey("events")
        With rsT
            .AddNew
            ![Title] = var1("title")
            ![Datex] = var1("date")
            ![Notes] = var1("notes")
            .Update
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

I've tried the solutions (and others similar) in these links.

https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web/issues/134   - I'm aware this is for exporting json and not importing, but I thought the syntax might help, as Tim Hall has replied himself. Unfortunately, The ".Data" property doesn't appear or work for me :(

[VBA-Json Parse Nested Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48994854/vba-json-parse-nested-json)   - When trying to apply this to the UK Bank Holidays json, I get Run-time error 13 again.

https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web/issues/329   - If I try, for example:

```
Debug.Print Parsed(dictionaryKey)
```

Then after then "item" function in JsonConverter, I get a Run-time error 449: Argument not optional.

https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web/issues/260   - I can't get to the stage to create a collection to use ".Count" to make this work.

If anyone has achieved this before in VBA, or might be able to offer a hand, it would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Forgot to mention references - I already have both Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library and Microsoft Scripting Runtime enabled.

Comment: In JSON, `[]` denotes an array, not a `Collection`.

Comment: I've published a small JSON library [here](https://github.com/erikvona/JSONInterpreter) that might be of help. If there's an issue parsing JSON with it, please share the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with learning how to read the json structure. You can paste the json string in a [json viewer](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?). You then get a nice view of the structure. In VBA JSON the [] denote a collection you can For Each over or access by index, and the {} denotes a dictionary you can For Each the keys of, or access by specific key.

If you put your json into a viewer you should be reading it something like as follows:

[image]

---

### Excel version for use as template:

**Accessing all items:**

The following shows one way of emptying the entire json into an array (you could amend for adding to recordset?)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub EmptyJsonIntoArray()

    Dim json As Object, r As Long, c As Long, results(), counter As Long

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json", False
        .Send
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responsetext) 'dictionary with 3 keys
    End With

    Dim key As Variant, innerKey As Variant, col As Collection
    Dim division As String, headers(), item As Object, arr()
    arr = json.keys
    headers = json(arr(LBound(arr)))("events").item(1).keys 'take first innermost dictionary keys as headers for output

    'oversize array as number of events can vary by division
    ReDim results(1 To 1000, 1 To UBound(headers) + 2) '4 is the number of keys for each event level dictionary. +1 so can have _
    division included as first column in output and +1 to move from 0 based headers array to 1 based results

    r = 1 'leave first row for headers
    results(1, 1) = "Division"
    For c = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
        results(1, c + 2) = headers(c)  'write out rest of headers to first row
    Next
    For Each key In json.keys 'england-and-wales etc. division
        division = key
        For Each item In json(division)("events") 'variable number of events dictionaries within collection
            r = r + 1: c = 2 'create a new row for event output. Set column to 2 (as position 1 will be occupied by division
            results(r, 1) = division
            For Each innerKey In item.keys 'write out innermost dictionary values into row of array
                results(r, c) = item(innerKey)
                c = c + 1
            Next
        Next
    Next
    'transpose array so can redim preserve the number of rows (now number of columns) to only required number based on current value of r
    results = Application.Transpose(results)
    ReDim Preserve results(1 To UBound(headers) + 2, 1 To r)
    results = Application.Transpose(results)  'transpose array back
    'STOP '<== View array
End Sub
```

---

**Sample of `results` contents:**

[image]

---

**Access:**

From feedback by OP. With Access there is no Application.Transpose. Instead array can be passed to the following function<sub>[source](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/arrays/transposing.htm)</sub>. However, the array must then be 0 based that is passed.

```
Public Function TransposeArray(myarray As Variant) As Variant 
Dim X As Long 
Dim Y As Long 
Dim Xupper As Long 
Dim Yupper As Long 
Dim tempArray As Variant 
    Xupper = UBound(myarray, 2) 
    Yupper = UBound(myarray, 1) 
    ReDim tempArray(Xupper, Yupper) 
    For X = 0 To Xupper 
        For Y = 0 To Yupper 
            tempArray(X, Y) = myarray(Y, X) 
        Next Y 
    Next X 
    TransposeArray = tempArray 
End Function
```

---

### Access version as appended by OP:

In addition to TransposeArray above (edited below to work in this case), here's the full code for Access:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Public Sub UpdateBankHolidays()
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim tBH As Recordset
    Dim i, r, c As Long
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    'Set recordset variable as existing table (in this case, called "z_BankHolidays")
    Set tBH = dbs.OpenRecordset("z_BankHolidays")

    'Download and parse json
    Dim json As Object, results(), counter As Long
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json", False
        .Send
        Set json = ParseJson(.responsetext)      'dictionary with 3 keys
    End With

    Dim key As Variant, innerKey As Variant, col As Collection
    Dim division As String, headers(), item As Object, arr()
    arr = json.Keys
    headers = json(arr(LBound(arr)))("events").item(1).Keys 'take first innermost dictionary keys as headers for output

    'oversize array as number of events can vary by division
    ReDim results(1 To 1000, 1 To UBound(headers) + 2) '4 is the number of keys for each event level dictionary. +1 so can have _
                                                       division included as first column in output and +1 to move from 0 based headers array to 1 based results

    r = 1                                        'leave first row for headers
    results(1, 1) = "Division"
    For c = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
        results(1, c + 2) = headers(c)           'write out rest of headers to first row
    Next
    For Each key In json.Keys                    'england-and-wales etc. division
        division = key
        For Each item In json(division)("events") 'variable number of events dictionaries within collection
            r = r + 1: c = 2                     'create a new row for event output. Set column to 2 (as position 1 will be occupied by division
            results(r, 1) = division
            For Each innerKey In item.Keys       'write out innermost dictionary values into row of array
                results(r, c) = item(innerKey)
                c = c + 1
            Next
        Next
    Next
    'transpose array so can redim preserve the number of rows (now number of columns) to only required number based on current value of r
    results = TransposeArray(results)
    ReDim Preserve results(0 To UBound(results), 0 To r)
    results = TransposeArray(results)            'transpose array back

    'Clear all existing bank holidays from recordset
    dbs.Execute "DELETE * FROM " & tBH.Name & ";"

    'Insert array results into tBH recordset, transforming the date into a date value using a dd/mmm/yyyy format (in the array they are currently yyyy-mm-dd)
    For i = 1 To r
        If results(i, 1) = "england-and-wales" Then
            dbs.Execute " INSERT INTO " & tBH.Name & " " _
                      & "(Title,Holiday,Notes) VALUES " _
                      & "('" & results(i, 2) & "', " & _
                        "'" & DateValue(Right(results(i, 3), 2) & "/" & Format("20/" & Mid(results(i, 3), 6, 2) & "/2000", "mmm") & "/" & Left(results(i, 3), 4)) & "', " & _
                        "'" & results(i, 4) & "'" & _
                        ");"
        End If
    Next

    'Finish
    MsgBox "Bank Holidays updated."

End Sub
```

It's also worth noting that I (OP) had to change X and Y in the TransposeArray to start from 1, not 0 (even though, as noted above and in comments, subsequently redimming it must be based at 0). I.e.:

```
Public Function TransposeArray(myarray As Variant) As Variant
Dim X As Long
Dim Y As Long
Dim Xupper As Long
Dim Yupper As Long
Dim tempArray As Variant
Xupper = UBound(myarray, 2)
Yupper = UBound(myarray, 1)
ReDim tempArray(Xupper, Yupper)
For X = 1 To Xupper
    For Y = 1 To Yupper
        tempArray(X, Y) = myarray(Y, X)
    Next Y
Next X
TransposeArray = tempArray
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you @QHarr! In MS Access, Application.Transpose doesn't exist, so I transposed manually using e.g. [https://bettersolutions.com/vba/arrays/transposing.htm](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/arrays/transposing.htm). Also, I was getting a "Run-time error 9: Subscript out of range" at `ReDim Preserve results(1 To UBound(headers) + 2, 1 To r)`, and even though `(lbound(results,1)` and `lbound(results,2)` gave 1, changing the line to `(ReDim Preserve results(0 To UBound(headers) + 2, 0 To r)` did the trick!

Comment: Brackets were a typo. Even though `lbound(results,1)` and `lbound(results,2)` both returned 1, changing the line to `ReDim Preserve results(0 To UBound(headers) + 2, 0 To r` did the trick! Thanks again.

Comment: N.B. Yes, it was me, with the candlestick, in the library

Comment: Would you mind editing my answer to include the final Access version at the bottom please? Makes it more useful to future readers.

Comment: Done. thanks again, the annotated picture was particularly helpful.